# $f (x,y)=\frac {x^2y}{x^3-y^2} $ is not continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Show that $f:\mathbb {R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb {R} $,  $f (x,y)=\frac {x^2y}{x^3-y^2} $ if $x^3\neq y^2$ and $0$ otherwise.

I have to prove that $f$ is not continuous.

I try to prove with sequence. If $x_n=y_n=\frac {1}{n} $ then the limit is 0. I need another sequences.

Comment: What happens on the line $y=x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x = y$, then $f(x,y) = f(x,x) = \frac{x^3}{x^3-x^2}.$ Observe that $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x,x) = \pm\infty$, yet $f(1,1) = 0$.

If you want to use sequences, take $x_n = y_n = 1+ \frac 1n$. In that case $f(x_n,y_n) = 1 + n$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that if $x=\dfrac1{n^2}+\dfrac1{n^3}$ and $y=\dfrac1{n^3}$, then$$f(x,y)=\frac{(1+n)^2}{3n^2+3n+1}\to\frac13.$$

Comment: How did you find that choice of $x$ and $y$ ?

Comment: The function takes the value $0$ at the points of the form $\left(\frac1{n^2},\frac1{n^3}\right)$. So, I took points very close to these ones, namely points of the form $\left(\frac1{n^2},\frac1{n^3}\right)+\left(\frac1{n^3},0\right)$.